# Visa telephone interview disconnected

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, applications, finland

I applied for a Finish Schengen tourist visa two weeks ago, so today I got a call from the Embassy and apparently it was from the visa officer who wanted to speak to me.

Unfortunately the phone was disconnected before we got far as I was somewhere with bad service, she had told me that she wants to ask me some questions. I tried to call back immediately but it was not picked up.

Do you think that can affect the visa decision? What should I do? Should I send them an email explaining what happened?

Comment: Of course it can affect the visa. They normally call if they need to clear up something before making a decision. If it’s a major issue they can deny the visa however if it’s not so important they can overlook and approve. Try as much as possible to contact them. It’s difficult to get hold of them on phone but try, and send off an email ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

try to call back and explain the situation until you get the updates on next steps/appointment call. Email may be slow to get a response.